# Captcha Dialog Layout (Android)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm adding a captcha dialog box to an Android app and am having difficulty getting it to size correctly. The captcha image is 120x50 and I want it to be scaled up to fit the width of the dialog box. With my current XML it fits the width, but covers up the buttons below.

[image]

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:id="@+id/captchaImage"
                   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                   android:scaleType="fitXY"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/captchaText"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    android:id="@+id/cancelCaptcha"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableLayout>
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:id="@+id/submitCaptcha"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea how I can get the 120x50 image to scale to the width of the dialog box without covering anything below it?

Thanks in advance,
MrGrinst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap every View in another `LinearLayout` or `TableLayout`, and you can take advantage of weights to let them size themselves. Give this a shot:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/captchaImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/captchaText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button android:id="@+id/cancelCaptcha"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/submitCaptcha"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome that works for the most part. Now I just need to extend the dialog box vertically so it has enough space to display the image. Right now the image is just compressed vertically. How would I go about making the dialog box height larger?

Comment: Try removing the `scaleType` attribute.